# Facing issue while running spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting both errors I am not sure why I am getting this error, Please help in resolving both the error. If Any further info needed Please revert back.

1st ERROR

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
> at project.art_area.ArtAreaApplication.main(ArtAreaApplication.java:19) ~[classes/:na]

2ND error

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "art_area.service.LoginServiceImpl.addCustomer(art_area.model.LoginDTO)" because "this.loginService" is null
> at art_area.api.LoginApi.addCustomer1(LoginApi.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
> at project.art_area.ArtAreaApplication.addCustomer(ArtAreaApplication.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
> at project.art_area.ArtAreaApplication.run(ArtAreaApplication.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:768) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
> ... 5 common frames omitted

```
Main Class:

package project.art_area;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration;

import art_area.api.LoginApi;
import art_area.model.LoginDTO;

@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = ArtAreaApplication.class)
public class ArtAreaApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ArtAreaApplication.class, args);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        addCustomer();
    }
    
    public void addCustomer()
    {
        LoginApi loginApi=new LoginApi();
        LoginDTO loginDTO=new LoginDTO();
        loginDTO.setFirstname("A");
        loginDTO.setLastname("B");
        loginDTO.setPhonenumber("1234567890");
        loginDTO.setDoctorname("A");
        loginDTO.setSex("M");
        String s=loginApi.addCustomer1(loginDTO);
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}

API Class:

package art_area.api;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import art_area.model.LoginDTO;
import art_area.service.LoginService;
import art_area.service.LoginServiceImpl;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public class LoginApi {
    
    @Autowired
    private LoginServiceImpl loginService;
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/customer")
    public String addCustomer1(LoginDTO loginDTO)
    {
        if(loginService.addCustomer(loginDTO));
        {
            return "customer Successfully added";
        }
        //return "customer already exists";
    }

}

Service Class:
package art_area.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import art_area.model.LoginDTO;
import art_area.repository.LoginRepository;

@Service(value = "loginService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService{

    @Autowired
    private LoginRepository loginRepository;
    
    @Override
    public boolean addCustomer(LoginDTO loginDTO) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(loginRepository.addCustomer(loginDTO))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main application class change the package

```
package project.art_area;
```

to

```
package art_area;
```

(Move the java class accordingly)

This change is needed to allow Spring smoothly auto-configure the managed beans.

Comment: By the looks of it author has decided to move/rename file in manual way which led to this issue. In order to avoid that issue in the future, I'd advise to use 'Refactor' option offered by IDE (any IDE have this option nowadays) and it will update all occurrences.

Comment: Thanks for reply. After changes, Still the issue persists.